# $y''+(\sin x)y=0$ series solutions - differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the first four nonzero terms in each of two powers series solutions about the origin. Show that they form a fundamental set of solutions.

$y''+(\sin x)y=0$

what will be the solutions of the above differential equation????

Comment: Was your question answered?

Comment: Google "Peano-Baker series".

Answer (score 2):

The author means you need to expand $y$ in Taylor expansion and match up the terms $(x-x_{0})^{n}$ with each other. Here you may use $x_{0}=0$ for simplificity and matching $x^{n}$ terms. Mind that you need to expand $\sin[x]$ into $x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+O(x^{5})$, etc as well.

Comment: I am still a little unsure how to solve this.

Comment: Here is an example:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/solution-of-differential-equation-by-taylor-series?rq=1

Comment: Why have you combined all powers from x^5 onwards?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers to this question aren't incorrect. Here is another way to solve it which is probably what you are used to seeing in your class or text book.

The first step is to recognize when they ask for a power series solution about the origin, they mean a power series solution about the point $x=0$. Since $y'' + sin(x)y = 0$ is already in standard form, we can see that $x=0$ is an ordinary point. The sine is analytic at $x=0$ so we don't have any singular points to worry about.

The next step is to use a Maclaurin series expansion for $\sin(x)$. Remember that Maclaurin series are Taylor series about the point $x=0$. If they asked for a power series solution about a point other then $x=0$, we would use the Taylor series expansion. The Maclaurin series expansion for $$
\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}
$$
You can now continue like you are most likely used to with a standard power series solution method for linear, simple variable coefficient, homogeneous differential equations. Take the second derivative of the power series : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n X^n$
$$
y''(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (n)(n-1)C_n X^{n-2}
$$
Substitute the power series summation for $y''(x)$, $y(x)$ and the Maclaurin series expansion for $\sin(x)$ into the original differential equation.
$$
\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n)(n-1)C_n X^{n-2}\right) 
+ \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}X^{2n+1}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n X^n\right) = 0
$$
The next step in a problem you are used to would be to re-index the summations to have the same power of $X$ and have the same starting point in the index. We won't be doing that for this problem. All you need to do is expand each summation and then factor.
$$
(2C_2 + 6C_3X + 12C_4 X^2 + 20C_5X^3 +...) \\+ (X - \frac{X^3}{6} + \frac{X^5}{120} +...)(C_0 + C_1X + C_2X^2 + C_3X^3 +...) = 0.
$$
One of the areas you can run into problems with doing expansions like the above is you don't expand to enough terms. Since there is a lot of typing involved I won't type it all out. When you factor through, group like terms. The minimum amount of terms required are shown below:
$$
(2C_2) + (C_0 + 6C_3)X + (C_1 + 12C_4)X^2 + (\frac{-C_0}{6} + C_2 + 20C_5)X^3 
\\+ (\frac{-C_1}{6} + C_3 + 30C_6)X^4 + (\frac{C_0}{120} 
\\- \frac{C_2}{6} + C_4 + 42C_7)X^5 +... = 0
$$
What you want to do now is similar to what you have done for constant coefficient solutions to differential equations. The thing to remember here is to put all the higher coefficients in terms of $C_0$ and $C_1$.
\begin{align}
X^0 &:& 2C_2 &= 0  &-> C_2 &= 0  \\
X^1 &:& C_0 + 6C_3 &= 0  &-> C_3 &= -\frac{1}{6}C_0  \\
X^2 &:& C_1 + 12C_4 &= 0  &-> C_4 &= -\frac{1}{12}C_1  \\
X^3 &:& \frac{-C_0}{6} + C_2 + 20C_5 &= 0  &-> C_5 &= \frac{C_0}{120}  \\
X^4 &:& \frac{-C_1}{6} + C_3 + 30C_6 &= 0  &-> C_6 &= \frac{C_1}{180} - \frac{C_3}{30}
\end{align}
Substitute what we already got for $C_3$ in terms of $C_0$.
\begin{align}
C_6 &= \frac{C_1}{180} + \frac{C_0}{180}
\\
X^5 &: \frac{C_0}{120} - \frac{C_2}{6} + C_4 + 42C_7 = 0  ~~~ -> C_7 = -\frac{C_0}{5040} - \frac{C_4}{42} = -\frac{C_0}{5040} + \frac{C_1}{504}
\end{align}

We can now substitute the above coefficients in the general power series expansion.
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n X^n = C_0 + C_1 X + C_2 X^2 + C_3 X^3 +...
$$
This becomes:
$$
C_0 + C_1 X - \frac{C_0}{6}X^3 - \frac{C_1}{12}X^4 + \frac{C_0}{120}X^5 + (\frac{C_1}{180} + \frac{C_0}{180})X^6 + (-\frac{C_0}{5040} + \frac{C_1}{504})X^7 +...
$$
Your general solution is :
$$
y(x) = C_0\left\{1 - \frac{1}{6}X^3 + \frac{1}{120}X^5 + \frac{1}{180}X^6 - \frac{1}{5040}X^7 +...\right\} \\+ C_1\left\{X - \frac{1}{12}X^4 + \frac{1}{180}X^6 + \frac{1}{504}X^7 + ...\right\}
$$
Since your question asked for two power series solutions, the general solution is $y(x) = (C_0)y_1(x) + (C_1)y_2(x)$.  These are two linearly independent solutions. Just take the above general solution and have $y_1(x)$ equal the $C_0$ portion, and have $y_2(x)$ equal the $C_1$ portion.

Comment: This answer is amazing, I was trying to do it with this fashion, thank you for posting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a homogeneous linear differential equation of order two whose coefficients $0$ (at $y'$) and $-\sin x$ (at $y$) are entire functions. From "general principles" it then follows that the solution space ${\cal L}$ is a two-dimensional vector space of entire functions, and that  ${\cal L}$ is spanned by the solutions $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ corresponding to the  initial data $y(0)=1, y'(0)=0$, resp.,  $y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$. Both $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have a Taylor expansion at the origin converging for all $x\in{\mathbb R}$ (or $z\in{\mathbb C}$), and introducing these expansions into the differential equation  will lead to recursion formulae for the Taylor coefficients of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

Doing the computations gives
$$\eqalign{Y_1(x)&=1-{x^3\over6}+{x^5\over120}+{x^6\over 180}-{x^7\over 5040}+ ?x^8 \cr Y_2(x)&=x-{x^4\over12}+{x^6\over180}+{x^7\over 504}+?x^8\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$y'' + \sin\pars{x}y = 0$

The solution is given by
$$
{\rm y}\pars{x} = C_{1}{\rm C}\pars{0,-2,{\pi \over 4} - {x \over 2}}
+ C_{2}{\rm S}\pars{0,-2,{\pi \over 4} - {x \over 2}}
$$
where ${\rm C}$ and ${\rm S}$ are Mathieu functions. $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ are constants. See [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MathieuDifferentialEquation.html) .